# How to get a nested value from a key inside of a @each loop in SCSS Map

Tags: sass

I am trying to access specific value from a key inside of a key in an @each loop from a SCSS map.

I need to have two left positions in the map: one for desktop and the other mobile but am having difficulty getting the values from left. I am not sure how to go about it.

I do have a [map-deep-get function](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/deep-getset-maps/) however inside of the @each loop it breaks. Is what I am attempting to do possible without another function?

I have some commented out attempts below but everything breaks. Not entirely sure how to approach, thanks for any help you can give.

```
$character-map: (
  billy: (
    name: 'billy',
    color: $colour-light-blue,
    left: (-1px, -2px),
  )
);

@each $key, $value in $character-map {
    &.dialogue-item-#{map-get($value, name)},
    &.guide-item-#{map-get($value, name)} {
        .character-head {
            background: lighten(map-get($value, color), 18%);
            border-color: map-get($value, color);

            // Actual Characters Head
            img {
               @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
                //left: map-get(($value, left), nth($value, 1));
                //left: map-get($value, nth(left, 1));
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out with a lot of experimenting, perhaps this will help someone who is looking.

if you change up the map a little bit you can do this.

```
$character-map: (
  billy: (
    name: 'billy',
    color: $colour-light-blue,
    left: (
        default: -9px,
        mobile: -2px
     ),
  )
);

@each $key, $value in $character-map {
    left: map-get(map-get($value, left), default);
}
```

Will compile to `left: 9px;`